# My R file won't generate in any of my projects?

Tags: java, android

My eclipse program is having trouble generating the R file for any project that I am working in. Is there someway I can fix this. How can I get the R file to generate again?

Comment: Try Project->Clean->Clean All Projects.

Comment: I did that but the R file still does not generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please just try this...
 first - delete gen folder
 then just build your project 
 
if build all project option is checked please uncheck this
 now build project and after build you have to clean project..
 your problem solved 
 after this you get problem please check error in detail and explain me..i try my best.....

Answer (score 0):

Save resources (and other files)

Check "Problems" window

Correct the shown errors in resources and other files

Save resources if necessary

Clean the project.

Exclude bin,gen from SVN/CVS

Commit the project.

Build again - R will be on its place

Some step could cause problems in the previous step. Then return to the appropriate step.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project. Project>>Clean project